# Java loop issue declaring variable

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

I am having an issue with the code below.

I need to make the surcharge variable equal to one of two values given a particular outcome and I  can only seem to get my surcharge value to equal R_RATE.

Where am I going wrong?

```
   String booking;
   double AddOn, trip, surcharge;  

   System.out.print("Enter booking type (A, B or C)");
   booking=sc.nextLine();

   double R_RATE_PERCENT = .5;
   double R_RATE = 5.0;

   if (booking.equals("A")
   {surcharge = S_Rate;

   if(booking.equals("B"))
   {       
   addOn = R_RATE;   

      if (addOn > trip * R_RATE_PERCENT) { 
      surcharge = trip * R_RATE_PERCENT;}

      else if (addOn < trip * R_RATE_PERCENT){
               surcharge = R_RATE;}
    }

   if(booking.equals("C"))
   {       
   addOn = F_RATE;   

      if (addOn > trip * F_RATE_PERCENT) { 
      surcharge = trip * F_RATE_PERCENT;}

      else if (addOn < trip * F_RATE_PERCENT){
               surcharge = F_RATE;}
```

Comment: can you give an example of the input and also the value of constants you are using?

Comment: Don't add information in comments. Look at the bottom of your post. See the edit link? Click it. Add information to your post. Click save. Done.

Comment: what is the value of trip?

Comment: A few notes : 1. use addOn instead of AddOn (variable naming convention as opposed to Class naming convention).
2. declare a final variable for trip * R_RATE_PERCENT instead of performing this calculation 3 times.
3. Edit your post so that your entire nested loop is showing. Can not help you without the entire code segment.

Comment: PS - based on you scanner usage i'd suggest using the following instead of : if(booking.equals("B")).....
http://ashtonkemerling.com/blog/2017/01/26/java-without-if/

Comment: @stinepike trip is an input from the user, a double variable

Comment: based on the code you edited - trip never receives a value, making it 0.0 at declaration.
This means that whenever the user inputs "B" , you should be at the if(AddOn>trip*R_RATE_PERCENT) case.

Comment: @RannLifshitz this is only part of the code I am having issue with, trip has a calculation made earlier in it, I didn't post the whole code as it is 200 or so lines so far. What is happening is that when the loop is finished surcharge = 5.0, it isn't displaying when the (AddOn>trip*R_RATE_PERCENT) is true.

Comment: Dude - if you want us to help you - POST ALL OF THE RELEVANT CODE!!!

Comment: @RannLifshitz Solved, took your advice to make a variable for trip*R_RATE and seems to work well, cheers for the help